# Webpack excluding dir does not work..

Tags: webpack

I am trying to exclude the directory of: \src\comps\app3\movies\
my syntax is:

```
config.module = {
    //preLoaders: [{test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint'}], // no need since I am using WebStorm to lint
    loaders: [
        // Support for .ts files.
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts',
            query: {
                'ignoreDiagnostics': [
                    2403, // 2403 -> Subsequent variable declarations
                    2300, // 2300 -> Duplicate identifier
                    2374, // 2374 -> Duplicate number index signature
                    2375  // 2375 -> Duplicate string index signature
                ]
            },
            exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, path.resolve(__dirname, "src/comps/app3/movies"), /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
        },
```

I also tried things like /movies/  as well as /movies/.ts$
but Webpack always tries and enter the movies dir...

no idea why... any suggestions are appreciated

Sean

Answer (score 1):

found the problem, if you are using a "exclude": [ ... in your tsconfig.ts, webpack will ignore the exclude you specify in webpack.config... so you need to specify only at ONE of the two places... hope it helps someone...